# MapStruct protobuf List to Pojo Mapping

Tags: mapstruct, grpc-java, protobuf-java

As part of GRPC api I am trying to map proto autogenerated classes to pojo. This is the .proto file

```
message AccountModelProto
{
 repeated VerificationModelProto verification = 1;
}
message VerificationModelProto
{
    string status = 1;
    string comment = 2;
    string verificationType = 3;
    repeated VerificationAttributeModelProto verificationAttributes = 4;
}
message VerificationAttributeModelProto
{
    string type = 1;
    string label = 2;
    bool attributeStatus = 3;
}
```

The mapper for the above code is. I referred to the examples provided by mapstruct according to it I don't need to provide explicit mapping of VerificationModelProto to List but I am getting compiler error

> error: Can't map property "Collection verification" to "VerificationModelProto verificationList". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "VerificationModelProto map(Collection value)".

```
@Mapping(source = "verification", target = "verificationList", qualifiedByName = "verificationModelToVerificationProtoMapping")
    AccountModelProto map(AccountModel accountModel);

@Named("verificationModelToVerificationProtoMapping")
default VerificationModelProto map (VerificationModel verificationModel)
{
    VerificationModelProto.Builder builder = VerificationModelProto.newBuilder()
                .setComment(verificationModel.getComment())
                .setStatus(verificationModel.getStatus().toString())
                .setVerificationType(verificationModel.getVerificationType());

    for(VerificationAttributeModel verificationAttributeModel: verificationModel.getVerificationAttributes())
    {
            builder.addVerificationAttributes(getVerificationAttributeBuilder(verificationAttributeModel));
    }
    return builder.build();
}

default VerificationAttributeModelProto getVerificationAttributeBuilder(VerificationAttributeModel verificationAttributeModel)
{
     VerificationAttributeModelProto.Builder builder = VerificationAttributeModelProto.newBuilder()
                .setAttributeStatus(verificationAttributeModel.getAttributeStatus())
                .setType(verificationAttributeModel.getType())
                .setLabel(verificationAttributeModel.getLabel());

   return builder.build();
}
```

How to get through this. I added CollectionMappingStrategy as CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED.

Comment: the erro is error: **Can't map property "Collection<VerificationModel> verification" to "VerificationModelProto verificationList". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "VerificationModelProto map(Collection<VerificationModel> value)".**